# Unable to execute a function because of if isset

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ftp

I am trying to make a web ftp explorer like [Monsta FTP](https://www.monstaftp.com/). Currently I'm trying to make a function that will switch the current directory to the directory I click on.

This is how it currently looks like:

[image: This is how I currently looks like]

The PHP (index.php):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['file_name'])) {
    $file_name = $_POST['file_name'];
    ftp_chdir($ftp_conn, $file_name);
    echo "<p>".ftp_pwd($ftp_conn)."<p>";
}

// connect to the FTP server
$ftp_server = "xxxxxxxxx";
$ftp_username = "xxxxxxxxx";
$ftp_userpass = "xxxxxxxxx";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server, 21) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
if ($ftp_conn === false) {
    echo "Unable connect to the ftp server.<br>";
} else {
    echo "Succesfully connected to the ftp server.<br>";
}

//login to the FTP server
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
if ($login === true) {
    echo "Succesfully logged in to the ftp server.";
} else {
    echo "Unable to log in to the ftp server.";
}

//get a list of all files and folders
$contents = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn, '/');
echo "<ul>";
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($contents) ; $i++) {
    echo "<li><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"post(this.id);\" id=\"".$contents[$i]."\">".$contents[$i]."</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>FTP file menager</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The JS (functions.js):

```
function post(vally) {
    var name = vally;
    $.post('index.php', {file_name:name}, function(data) {});
    console.log('posted');
}
```

When I click on one of the links with the folder name, I get "posted" in the console meaning that JQuery (I'm using JQuery 3.2.1 downloaded from [jquery.com](https://jquery.com)) posted the data but I don't get any alerts or echos from PHP. I tried putting the `if ()` before and after the connection to the ftp server has been established, but I still get nothing.

Does anyone have an idea on why my code doesn't work?

Comment: Nothing happens in a callback function, what do you expect?

Comment: I expect ftp_pwd (echo "<p>".ftp_pwd($ftp_conn)."<p>";) to return the name of the current directory but I don't get anything.

Comment: What is the response from ajax request in developers console?

Comment: try to add `ftp_pwd($ftp_conn)` after `ftp_connect()` executed
corresponding to php docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pwd.php

Comment: @u_mulder I console logged the `data` variable and I got all of the HTML code that is written in the file.

Comment: So, what do you want then?

Comment: @Joseph when I put `ftp_pwd($ftp_conn)` after `ftp_connect()` I get nothing and when I put it after `ftp_login()` I get `/`.

Comment: @u_mulder I want to get the name of the current directory _after_ I click on the directory I want to go into which will then mean that php got the ajax data and I would then enter the desired directory.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work because php only writes html to the file before it loads and not after but still there should be be a solution to this.

Comment: Data returned by ajax request should be outputted somehow. You __do nothing__ with returned data. So - what do you expect then?

Comment: The AJAX gives data to PHP, the if statement should get triggered because 'file_name' isset and should then tell the ftp server to switch to the directory I tell it to. I don't need the AJAX data, I need PHP to output the ftp data when I ask it to through AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `ftp_close($ftp_conn);` because it closes the ftp connection before the js gets loded and therefore php can no longer execute ftp commands, unless you open the ftp connection in the `isset()`.